# How To Create Git Fork From Local Copy of Upstream Repo

Tags: git, github

I'm in a bit of a bind. A forked repo I control got out of hand with merge conflicts so I decided to clone the upstream repo and reapply my changes.

I cloned the upstream repo and started reapplying my changes. **Lots of changes**. The problem is, I intended to make these changes on my fork of the upstream repo with the intention of making a PR later, but I ended up making changes on the upstream repo directly (by cloning the original repo instead of my fork). I am unable to commit to this repo directly, and must commit to my fork instead.

How can I commit the changes I made on the cloned upstream repo to my forked repo?

I've read several articles on how to reset forked repos and set new origins but I'm afraid of losing my changes so I wanted to ask the directly for my situation.

I need to:

1. Reset my fork to match the upstream repo
2. Commit my changes on the clone of the upstream repo to my "reset" fork

My "Plan B" is to back everything up. Reset my fork to the upstream repo. Then reapply the changes to my fork. But since I've already reapplied thousands of lines of changes over many files I would like to avoid doing that again.

I apologize for not providing additional details and commands I've tried so far. I'm making another backup currently before I try any commands, because I cannot lose these changes. Thank you for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE**

I've reset my fork to match the upstream repo. Now I just need to push the changes I've made to my clone of the upstream repo to my fork. This should be something simple like adding a new remote origin correct? Something like `git remote add origin <my_fork_url>`? If I do that, how can I commit and push to my fork?

**RESOLUTION**

Resetting the fork so that it was in sync with the upstream repo was straightforward enough. My primary question involved how to change the `origin` repo, which is possible with `git remote set-url origin <fork_url>`. This allowed me to change the `origin` associated with my local clone of the upstream repo, essentially setting the origin to my fork.

Comment: _"Reset my fork to match the upstream repo"_ clone the repo again? If you're using github, why not delete the repo and re-fork it?

Comment: I've submitted PR's in the past and my impression is deleting my current fork will screw up previous PR's. I can delete and re-fork if I need to. Is there a git command that can create a fork directly from a cloned (upstream) repo that changes have been made locally on? I really don't want to have to reapply all my changes for the second time if it's possible to just create a fork from my local (upstream) repo.

Comment: `git remote set-url` allowed me to set a new origin on my local repo. I set the new origin to my fork, while the upstream is the original. I believe this fixes the issue!

Comment: Worth noting: *Git* does not actually *have* the concept of a "fork". Forks are specific to hosting sites such as GitHub and Bitbucket: they serve those sites' owners by encouraging their users to stay there, and not move to some other hosting site, since they'll potentially lose the fork-ness of their forks. I added [tag:github] to your tags here, since preserving GItHub fork-ness is a GitHub-specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving the issue bit using the git command line on the local upstream and forked/origin repos.

To reset the forked repo so that it is in sync with upstream, I did the following (Warning, this will erase all changes in the forked repo):

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git reset --hard upstream/master
git push origin master --force
```

Then, on the cloned upstream repo that I made changes on, I updated the remote origin with the following:

```
git remote set-url origin <fork_url>
```

Finally, I can commit the changes I made on the upstream clone directly to my fork.